# Keep getting syntax error, but I can't detect any

Tags: php, mysql

Perhaps anyone here can help me to look for any errors in this block of code. Since I've been looking for it for few days but couldn't find any. Please help me. Thank you.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$tid = $_GET['tid'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ftopics WHERE categoryId ='".$id."' AND id='".$tid."' LIMIT 1";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

                   if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 1){
                   echo "<table width = '100%'>";
                   if ($_SESSION['user']){
                   echo "<tr><td colspan = '2'><input type = 'submit' value = 'Add Reply' onClick=\"window.location=
                   'postReply.php?id=".$id."&tid=".$tid."'\" />";
                   echo "  | <a href='main.php'>Back to main page</a><hr />";
                   }
                   else {
                    echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>
                    <p>Please log in to add your reply.</p></td></tr>";
                    }
                    while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
                          $title = $row['topicTitle'];
                          $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM fposts WHERE categoryId='".$id."' AND topicId='".$tid."'";
    `                     $res2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
                          while ($row2=mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)){
                            $creator = $row2['postCreator'];
                            $date = $row2['postDate'];
                            $content = $row2['postContent'];
                                       echo "<tr><td valign='top' style='border:1px solid #000000;'>";
                                       echo "<div style='min-height:125px;'>".$title;
                                       echo "<br>by ".$creator." - ".$date."<hr />".$content."</div></td><td width='200' valign ='top'";
                                       echo "align='center' style ='border:1px solid #000000;'>User Info Here</td></tr><tr><td colspan ='2'><hr /></td></tr>";
                                       }
```

Comment: what error where it occurs give actual error info ?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' ..... on line 108. line 108 is this: $creator = $row2['postCreator'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know but you might have accidentally placed **`** that extra backtick within your code

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM fposts WHERE categoryId='".$id."' AND topicId='".$tid."'";
    `                     $res2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
   ^^^//over here
```

Remove that and it will work as charm

Comment: @imfarihah You are welcome.. You can accept one of these answer so that this question might be considered as closed

Answer (score 1):

Remove the unwanted character(`) in between the below lines as follows:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM fposts WHERE categoryId='".$id."' AND topicId='".$tid."'";
$res2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes may be you can remove those extra quotes from the sql

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ftopics WHERE categoryId = ".$id." AND id=".$tid." LIMIT 1";

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM fposts WHERE categoryId=".$id." AND topicId=".$tid.";
```

Try that out.

Comment: I've tried, but still I got error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' ..... on line 108.
line 108 is this: $creator = $row2['postCreator'];